# C++ unable to use super class' methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, superclass

I feel stupid right now, haven't been doing C++ in ages, can't understand what's wrong... However I got this following class:

```
#include <string>
class NamedObject
{
    public:
        NamedObject();
        virtual ~NamedObject();
        virtual std::string getName() const { return m_name };
        virtual void setName(const std::string name) { m_name = name };
    private:
        std::string m_name;
};
```

And now I'm inheriting a simple class out of it:

```
#include "NamedObject.h"
enum eTeam { eAttacker, eDefender, eSpectator, eNone };
class Player : public NamedObject
{
    public:
        Player();
        virtual ~Player();
        virtual void printName();
        virtual eTeam getTeam() const { return m_team };
        virtual void setTeam(const eTeam team) { m_team = team };
    private:
        std::string m_name;
        eTeam m_team;
};
```

However, I am unable to use player->setName("blabla") from my main.cpp? Here's the main file:

```
#include "Player.h"
int main()
{
    Player* p1 = new Player();
    p1->setName("Name Changed!")
    p1->printName(); // prints "Unnamed" since I declared that in default ctor
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, everything runs up well, the name just doesn't simply change. Also, I got all of the constructors and destructors, as well as my `printName`-method working perfectly, and the problem is not within them.

Comment: And it's not the missing ';' after `setName()` ?

Comment: No it's not, I obviously rewrote the whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is that `setName` modifies the `m_name` in the parent class and `printName` prints out the `m_name` of the derived class because you're redeclaring `std::string m_name;` in the derived class.

Remove the declaration from the derived class and mark `m_name` as `protected` member in the parent class:

```
#include <string>
class NamedObject
{
public:
    NamedObject();
    virtual ~NamedObject();
    virtual std::string getName() const { return m_name };
    virtual void setName(const std::string name) { m_name = name };
protected:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

You could also keep `m_name` private and use the method `getName()` instead, as suggested by moswald.

Comment: Thanks to you and thanks to everyone else, I feel so stupid now :D been coding Python too much and simply forgot such a basic thing.

Comment: I would avoid making it `protected`. There's already a `getName`; he should just use that instead of accessing `m_name` directly.

Comment: Yes I did that already, just didn't notice that I was replacing the m_name.

Answer (score 2):

You created another different variable `m_name` in your derived class that shadowed the one in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that must not be your real code.

Your derived/super class is redeclaring m_name.  Probably not what you mean to do;)

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not his real code. Likely, that's the bug.